# Как создать пагинацию для текста в новости?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста, допустим есть выводимая новость из БД состоящая из допустим 1050 слов, как сделать так чтобы в самой новости была пагинация по страницам (допустим 100 слов на страницу)
Вот код вывода новостей:

```
<?php 
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC");



while($myrow=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo "<b><a class=title>".$myrow['title']."</a></b>";
    echo "<a class=title_d>".$myrow['date_news']."</a><br><hr>";
    if(isset($_GET['full']) && $_GET['full']==$myrow['id'])
    {
        echo "<div class=scroll><a class=mess>".$myrow['fullnews']."<br><br></a></div>";
        echo "<a href=books.php>Скрыть</a><hr><br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<a class=mess>".$myrow['shortnews']."<br><br></a>";
        echo "<a href=books.php?full=".$myrow['id']." class=button_full>Читать полностью</a><br><br><br>";

    }


}
?>
```

Comment: Пробовали в php разбить строку по пробелам (при желании можно дополнительно обработать и какие-нибуть особые случаи, но думаю в этом нет особой необходимости) и вывести первые 100 слов, затем 100 слов из оставшихся ...?

Answer (score 1):

Ну ответ лежит в основе вашего вопроса. Вам нужно написать скрипт, который будет обрабатывать каждую страницу "новости" отдельно. Т.е. отвечать на запрос типа `news/newsname/3`. В этом скриптике вы просто делаете запрос к бд с условием ограничения по длинне контента (100 слов например).

Для MySQL есть вот такие вот функции :

`string LEFT( str string, len integer)`. 
Возвращает len первых символов из строки str. Поддерживает многобайтовые символы.

`string SUBSTRING(str string FROM pos integer FOR len integer)`

Возвращает подстроку строки str длиною len символов с позиции pos. Поддерживает многобайтовые символы.

Comment: `LEFT` разделит по символам, а нужно по словам.

Comment: Ближе всего `SUBSTRING_INDEX` но для страниц дальше первой, придётся ещё делать вырезание предыдущей части строки, что на мой взгляд уже SQL изврещение.

Comment: Ну резать на слова это уже точно отдельный кусок кода должен обрабатывать. @Arnial согласен - там уже будет сложней. Поэтому решение плавно перерастает в деление на блоки именно на уровне php чем на уровне MySQL.